# cannot display Image

Tags: java, drawimage

I'm new being in programming, can you please tell me what is the problem in my code. The 
        fillOval is operating well but trying to replace it with .gif file get failed, window is opened by 
        nothing is viewed...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

int x;
int y;

int inix=500;
int iniy=500;

int i=0; 
private void moveBall() {
    /*x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;*/
    double degrees=(double) i;
    double radians=Math.toRadians(degrees);
    double Sinu=Math.sin(radians);
    double Sinu200=Math.sin(radians)*200;
    int SinuInt=(int) Sinu200;
    //y=500+SinuInt;
    y=iniy+SinuInt;
    double Cos=Math.cos(radians);
    double Cos200=Math.cos(radians)*200;
    int CosInt=(int) Cos200;
    //x=500+CosInt;
    x=inix+CosInt;


    i++;
    if (i==360){ i=0;}

            //System.out.println(Sinu+"   "+Sinu200+"   "+SinuInt +"   "+x);

        }


private int sin(double radians) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

    @Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    //g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    //g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/Images/MyIm.gif");
    g2d.drawImage(img1, x, y, this);


}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        game.moveBall();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(2);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: write `if (img1 == null) System.out.println("null");` under `Image img1`, See if it is null or not

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep()` in a `Swing` program. Use a `Swing Timer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure where your problem is, but my very best guess would be:

your image location is not suitable! (ignore the other classes, it's just a test project ^^)

i've copy/pasted your code, i used my custom image and it works fine with me!

[image: location of image]

make an folder in your eclipse project BUT NOT IN YOUR SOURCE dir (!!!) and then refer to the image like this:

```
Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img/index.png");
```

Comment: set answer as correct answer please ^^, if it solved your problem (it seems it did ^^)

Comment: Yes you did... answer set.