# Decoding Bitmap returns a null

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

This appears to be a common issue here in Stackoverflow, most appear to be errors relating to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802820/bitmapfactory-decodestream-always-returns-null-and-skia-decoder-shows-decode-ret). However, I think mine is different. I am loading my image from the internal storage, so it should not have download time issues that cause the aforementioned bug.

This is some stripped down code that I use to fill the ImageView with the file.

```
Options opts = new Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 1;
opts.inPurgeable = true;
opts.inInputShareable = true;
opts.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];

Bitmap bm = null;
try {
    // Use BufferedInputStream to attempt to alleviate null bitmap errors. This is/used to be an [Android bug.
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile)), null, opts);
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    // File is probably too big, try down-sampling
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // The input File was not found
}

if(bm != null) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
} else {
    // Give a warning
}
```

This works with some of my files, and not with others. I have [uploaded the images I am testing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1doiy.jpg). I made all 3 with pre-existing filters from GIMP. None of the files give me OutOfMemory errors.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1doiy.jpg):

- Works: Yes
- ffprobe: Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 100x100
- Size: 5816 bytes

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxwyu.jpg):

- **Works: No**
- ffprobe: Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 200x200
- Size: 48781 bytes

Received in logcat:

> D/skia(16422): ------ png error Read Error!
>
> D/skia(16422): --- decoder->decode returned false

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LobzO.jpg):

- Works: Yes
- ffprobe: Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 175x175
- Size: 2589 bytes

Comment: Looks like image 2 is corrupted or the android png parser has some bugs.  If you have the original I'd try regenerating the png in photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
 inSampleSize = 2;
```

or can you look at this :
[BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returns null and skia decoder shows decode returned false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802820/bitmapfactory-decodestream-always-returns-null-and-skia-decoder-shows-decode-ret)

I think the size is the problem.

Comment: I have previously downsampled the picture by: options.inSampleSize = 4; With no change.

Comment: can you try  firstly the second image

Comment: I re-ran the test. With the same result. inSampleSize = 2; No change. inSampleSize = 4; No change. When it is applied to all images, 1 & 3 are vastly reduced in size (as expected).

Comment: can you try this : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636425/image-reading-error**

Comment: The image location is : "/data/data/packagename/cache/mailbox/23.test1.png". It should be fine for access. If it wasn't then it wouldn't load any images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802820/bitmapfactory-decodestream-always-returns-null-and-skia-decoder-shows-decode-ret can you look at this

Comment: I already investigated that link. It is even in my original post (albeit not very visible)

Comment: can you replace different image with same name with **image2** because I want to know is the image is problem or code?

Comment: File name makes no difference to the result. The files also have permissions: -rw-r--r--

Comment: I mean please put different image instead of image 2 with same name , so maybe it does not give error (maybe the problem is image?)