# Can't animate graphics in Java game

Tags: java, swing, animation, bufferedimage

I can't figure out how to animate my graphics. I've been using few tutorials and I didn't suceed. Here's my Animation class (taken from some random tutorial):

```
public Animation(){

}

public void setFrames(BufferedImage[] images){
    frames=images;
    if(currentFrame >= frames.length) currentFrame=0;
}

public void setDelay(long d){
    delay = d;                
}

public void update(){
    if(delay==-1) return;      
    long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000;        
    if(elapsed>delay){
        currentFrame++;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    if (currentFrame == frames.length) {
        currentFrame=0;           
    }      
}

public BufferedImage getImage(){         
    return frames[currentFrame];
}
}
```

My Player class looks like that:

```
public class Player {
private static ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon(Player.class.getResource("/Images/trollface.jpg"));
private static int x=360;
private static int y=400;
public static int Xdisplacement; //both unused anyways
public static int Ydisplacement;



public static Image getImage(){
    return player.getImage();
}    //other setters, getters n stuff
```

I have also got a different class for drawing pictures called DrawAll, here it is:

```
public class DrawAll extends Board {
public static void draw(){

    drawBG();
    drawWall();       
    drawTile();
    drawCrate();
    drawPlayer(); 
}

private static void drawPlayer(){
    Drawer.drawImage(Player.getImage(), Player.getX(), Player.getY(), null);
}
private static void drawBG(){
    Drawer.drawImage(WorldBackground.getBG(), 0, 0, null);
}
// other draw methods below
```

Board is my panel that I draw on, that listens to keys etc etc. I made my .GIF with 5 sprites(one file), 40x40  x5. Now I would like them to animate. I tried like everything, making methods in Animation static, "copying" methods from Animation class to my Player class etc. Of course I know how to "cut" my image on subimages, that's not an issue. Just can't make them change on my Panel. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is there a thread updating the view? its not visible in your code.

Comment: Well, I've got class that extends KeyAdapter in which I check what key was pressed or if collision occurs, then I update positions(x&y coordinates) of Player and Crates. Of course if it's that what you asked about.

Comment: Then you call repaint() on your panel I guess probably in this Drawer class? I dont think the GIF thing will work, you will have to split it into images.

Comment: maybe this question has some value for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633703/cannot-display-image/20634034#20634034 it's all about drawing an animation (well - not an array of images but a changing position, but basically it's the same)